Is the Chrome Verified Access API compatible with ChromeOS Flex?
I supervise a fleet of ~300 Chromebooks, and I use the Chrome Verified Access API to verify that the device belongs to the correct fleet when talking to my server.
For the next devices to buy, we were tempted to go for a Microsoft Surface 4 with ChromeOS Flex.
I have read through the documentation, but I did not find any mention of ChromeOS Flex. Knowing that it might deal with hardware requirements with the TPM, I was wondering if the compatibility was guaranteed.
Has anybody successfully used the Chrome Verified Access API on Chrome OS Flex?
